# Exponential function of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the last part of a problem:

For which $2\times 2$ orthogonal matrices does 
$$
e^A = I + A+ \frac{A^2}{2!}+ \cdots
$$
converge to an orthogonal matrix.

We need to show that if $A^*A=AA^*=I$ then when do we have $(e^A)^*e^A=e^A(e^A)^*=I$.  But then aligning powers of $A$ and $A^*$ is a bit nasty...

Comment: related: http://cs.brynmawr.edu/~dxu/206-2550-2.pdf

Comment: @vadim123 where should I be looking in this article?  I only see it taking logs of matrices...

Comment: $e^A$ is in $SO(n)$ if and only if $A$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit on how you arrived at this conclusion

Comment: From the first page of the article I cited.

Comment: I was hoping for not just the answer, but a way to arrive at in an exam situation.

Comment: If you're looking for an answer that uses specific tools that you have, then you should explain what those tools are in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $e^\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $e^A$. Show that if both $A$ and $e^A$ are orthogonal, the eigenvalues of $A$ must be some *unique* conjugate pair of complex numbers.
2. Every real normal matrix is orthogonally equivalent to its *real* Jordan form (the real analogue of the complex Jordan normal form), i.e. $A=QJQ^T$ where $Q$ is orthogonal and $J$ is a real Jordan form. In particular, for a $2\times2$ real matrix with eigenvalues $a\pm bi$, its real Jordan form is the matrix $\pmatrix{a&-b\\ b&a}$.